# Red X shown in VB.NET chart

Tags: vb.net, memory, charts

I have code that calculates stress at multiple points on a tank and then graphs these stresses on a Chart. I'll be viewing charts with no problem, and all of a sudden, the chart displays a red X and I need to close my program to view the stress results again.

[image: Red X]

I know there's no bug in my code. No exception is thrown. Any suggestions?

```
    Public Sub Graph(Curves) 'Creates the Graphs
    crtStressData.Series.Clear()
    crtStressData.Legends.Clear()
    'Dimension arrays for data points
    FileClose()
    Dim data As Double
    Dim StressTitle As String
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim BorderSize As Integer = 4
    'set up main graph
    crtStressData.ChartAreas(0).CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
    crtStressData.ChartAreas(0).CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
    crtStressData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = True
    crtStressData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = True
    crtStressData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = False
    crtStressData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = False
    Dim LegendName As String = ""
    StressTitle = TankName + " " + GraphType + " Stresses: " + strLoad + " Loading"
    If GraphType = "Combined" Then
        'Set component parameters
        'Create Combined Graph
        Call CreateDataPoints()
        'Add title, 
        crtStressData.Titles(0).Text = StressTitle
        For i = 0 To Curves - 1 'add legends
            If i = 0 Then
                LegendName = "Minimum Principal Stress"
            ElseIf i = 1 Then
                LegendName = "Minimum Principal Stress Location"
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                LegendName = "Maximum Principal Stress"
            ElseIf i = 3 Then
                LegendName = "Maximum Principal Stress Location"
            End If
            crtStressData.Series.Add(LegendName)
            ''work on legend name
            crtStressData.Series(i).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line 'sets as a line graph
            crtStressData.Series(i).XAxisType = DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Primary
            crtStressData.Series(i).YAxisType = DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Primary
            crtStressData.Series(i).BorderWidth = BorderSize
            For j = 0 To MaxDataPoints 'add points per legend type
                'set up which data to add and define color
                If i = 0 Then
                    '   StressType(k) = "Minimum Principal Stress"
                    data = SMINMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.Blue
                ElseIf i = 1 Then
                    '      StressType(k) = "Minimum Principal Stress Location"
                    data = SMINLOCData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.Green
                ElseIf i = 2 Then
                    'StressType(k) = "Maximum Principal Stress"
                    data = SMAXMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue
                ElseIf i = 3 Then
                    ' StressType(k) = "Minimum Principal Stress Location"
                    data = SMAXLOCData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.Red
                End If
                'add data and color
                crtStressData.Series(i).Points.AddXY(XPosData(j), data)
                crtStressData.Series(i).Color = color
            Next
            k = k + 1
        Next
    Else ' GraphType = "Components" 
        crtStressData.Series.Clear()
        'Set component parameters
        'Create Component Graph
        Call CreateDataPoints()
        'Add title and axes labels
        crtStressData.Titles(0).Text = StressTitle
        For i = 0 To Curves - 1 'add legends
            If i = 0 Then
                LegendName = "Bending"
            ElseIf i = 1 Then
                LegendName = "Pressure (X)"
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                LegendName = "Tension (X)"
            ElseIf i = 3 Then
                LegendName = "Total (X)"
            ElseIf i = 4 Then
                LegendName = "Pressure (Y)"
            ElseIf i = 5 Then
                LegendName = "Shear"
            End If
            crtStressData.Series.Add(LegendName) 'creates line
            crtStressData.Series(i).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line 'sets as a line graph
            crtStressData.Series(i).XAxisType = DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Primary
            crtStressData.Series(i).YAxisType = DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Primary
            crtStressData.Series(i).BorderWidth = BorderSize
            For j = 0 To MaxDataPoints 'add points per legend
                If i = 0 Then
                    'StressType(k) = "Bending"
                    data = SXBMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.Blue
                ElseIf i = 1 Then
                    '    StressType(k) = "Pressure (X)"
                    data = SXPMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.Green
                ElseIf i = 2 Then
                    '   StressType(k) = "Tension (X)"
                    data = SXTMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue
                ElseIf i = 3 Then
                    'StressType(k) = "Total (X)"
                    data = SXMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.Red
                ElseIf i = 4 Then
                    '    StressType(k) = "Pressure (Y)"
                    data = SYMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.HotPink
                ElseIf i = 5 Then
                    ' StressType(k) = "Shear"
                    data = SSMAXData(j)
                    color = Drawing.Color.DarkOrange
                End If
                'add data and color
                crtStressData.Series(i).Points.AddXY(XPosData(j), data)
                crtStressData.Series(i).Color = color
            Next
            k = k + 1
        Next
    End If
    'LEGEND
    Dim StressLegend As Legend = New Legend()
    StressLegend.IsDockedInsideChartArea = False
    StressLegend.Docking = Docking.Bottom
    StressLegend.Font = New Font("Gil Sans MT", 11)
    StressLegend.TextWrapThreshold = 100
    StressLegend.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    crtStressData.Legends.Add(StressLegend)
    crtStressData.Dock = DockStyle.None
    crtStressData.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your program is most likely running out of graphics memory allotted to it.  You might need to dispose of some controls over time if they are no longer used.

Comment: Can you post the drawing code? As @rory.ap states; you should dispose your graphic related objects.

Comment: code is posted.

Comment: I guess I'm unsure where to put the line "crtStressData.Dispose()." This chart was defined in the design so I can't really dispose of it in runtime, if you know what i mean

Comment: Hmm, yes, and clearing it would be the proper step to take.

Comment: You'll see the red X when the control's OnPaint() method or Paint event throws an exception.  So there *is* an exception, it however gets caught to produce the X.  You'll need to find out why.  Use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and tick the "CLR Exceptions" checkbox to force the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I did that and the debugger is not stopping at the exception. Also, I have found that it is only one set of data that is causing the chart and all subsequent data sets to show the "red X." Still unsure of the issue...